# "import fasttext_pybind as fasttext" Getting ImportError: generic_type: type "args" is already registered

Tags: python, c, fasttext

From my `C` code, I am calling the `fasttext` language classifier. The `fasttext` language classifier is a `python` file. Now the `python` file is importing `fasttext`.
Now I am required to call this `python` file many a times from my `C` code on different different texts. The first call to this `python` file is working fine and is giving me the output.
But from the immediate next call to this I am getting the above `error` while importing `fasttext`.

My `C` code which calls the language detector is the following.
The first line of the python file `languagedetector.py` has `import fasttext`
which internally is calling `import fasttext_pybind as fasttext` (as I get it from trace)

And while doing so I get

```
ImportError: generic_type: type "args" is already registered!
```

How to get rid off this error.

Can anyone please help?

```
        Py_SetProgramName("python3");
        Py_Initialize();
        wchar_t *argv[3];
        argv[0] = Py_DecodeLocale("/home/languagedetector.py", NULL);
        argv[1] = Py_DecodeLocale("-t", NULL);
        argv[2] = Py_DecodeLocale("Hi DEbapriyay", NULL);
        PySys_SetArgv(3,&argv);
        FILE *file = fopen("/home/languagedetector.py", "r");
        PyRun_SimpleFile(file, "/home/languagedetector.py");
        PyMem_RawFree(argv[0]);
        PyMem_RawFree(argv[1]);
        PyMem_RawFree(argv[2]);
        Py_Finalize();
```